# Скругление углов для таблицы

Tags: html, css

Имеется таблица:

```css
table {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 min-height: 300px;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 border-radius: 15px;
}

table td {
 border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>lplplpf</td>
   <td>pelfplfpf</td>
   <td>pflpelf</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>dlpdlwp</td>
   <td>dlpdwl</td>
   <td>sdplpsdl</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>ldsplp</td>
   <td>dslpdlpa</td>
   <td>dpsldpl</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Нужно скруглить углы у таблицы. Свойство `border-radius` не помогает.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так скруглять не будет, это особенность таблиц.
Замените `collapse` на `separate` для таблицы и скругляйте угловые ячейки.

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 300px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

table td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

table tr:first-child td:first-child {
    border-radius: 15px 0 0 0;
}

table tr:first-child td:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 15px 0 0;
}

table tr:last-child td:first-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 0 15px;
}

table tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>lplplpf</td>
        <td>pelfplfpf</td>
        <td>pflpelf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>dlpdlwp</td>
        <td>dlpdwl</td>
        <td>sdplpsdl</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ldsplp</td>
        <td>dslpdlpa</td>
        <td>dpsldpl</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: А если по дизайну требуется именно collapse?

Comment: @andreymal Не всё, что взбредет в голову дизайнеру, возможно реализовать. Именно с таблицей это невозможно, но вы можете попробовать сверстать это иначе, на флекс или еще как-то.

Comment: @andreymal Чтобы убрать отступы необходимо добавить border-spacing: 0;

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Таблица</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>

    <tr>
      <td>Lorem</td>
      <td>Lorem</td>
      <td>Lorem</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Lorem</td>
      <td>Lorem</td>
      <td>Lorem</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Lorem</td>
      <td>Lorem</td>
      <td>Lorem</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</body>

<style type="text/css">

  table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    /*При желании можешь добавить*/
    /* border: 1px solid;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;*/ 
  }

  p { background: #eee; text-align: center; }  

  table td {
    padding: 10px 25px;
    border: 1px solid;
  }
  table td {
    padding: 10px 25px;
  }
  table tr:first-child td:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  }
  table tr:first-child td:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  }

</style>

</html>
```